# Recommended modifier order

Tags: modifiers, armature

I have a mesh with the following modifiers: Lattice, Armature, Mask, and Mirror.

What is the recommended order for these modifiers?
The modifiers will only be applied during FBX export.

Comment: The recommended modifier order is the one you'd like it to be. If you want mesh to be affected by lattice on both its sides (mirrored and original) then you put Mirror below and Lattice above. If you want edits you make with lattice to be only on one side of the mesh put the Mirror above.

Comment: I guess my main concern then is the Armature modifier. Is it usually put in the beginning or end of the modifier stack?